# Precisely resizing master pane in xmonad

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, xmonad

In the default layout in xmonad, I know I can resize windows horizontally with mod-l and mod-h but these actions resize by too much.
I want to make very small adjustments to window sizes.
I played with the `delta` value in `xmonad.sh`
(the `percent of screen to increment by when resizing panes`) but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Which values for `delta` have you tried?

Comment: @Steven E.g. `1/100`, `3/100`, `1/1000`, `1/10`, `0.1/100`. Each time I change the value, I save `xmonad.hs`, and hit mod-q to restart xmonad, but the behavior of mod-l and mod-h doesn't change.

Comment: I don't know xmonad, but on Windows I use a wonderful window sizing utility called Sizer.  Perhaps something on this list of Linux alternatives to Sizer will be useful?  http://alternativeto.net/software/sizer/?platform=linux

Comment: please post your xmonad.hs